# Dapper not adding parameters

Tags: sql, odbc, informix, dapper

I am trying to use Dapper for our complex queries to remove any lost overhead that was previously existing with NH.

I have the following query (note this has been considerably shrunk):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM  tasks t 
WHERE t.initials = @UserInits
```

Which is called via our repository as so:

```
taskRepo.RawExec<TaskListItemDTO>(Query,new {UserInits = "SAS"})
```

Our implementation of DapperExec consist as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<T> RawExec<T>(string SQL, object param)
{
   return _session.Connection.Query<T>(SQL,param);
}
```

But Dapper doesn't appear to be adding the parameters to the query, and as a result, we are getting syntax errors.

Incase it helps, we are connecting over ODBC to Informix.

Thanks

Update Code Sample:

Sorry it took so long, been very busy with work! Below is a sample for MS SQL (2008) Server that should simple query the sys.all_objects (systables?) with a param value of 1 or 0 - but in this sample, as ODBC does not use named params, this won't work.

```
using Dapper;
using DapperSQL;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace DapperTests
{
    public class SQLEx
    {
        private OdbcConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var cnn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=ODBCSOURCE");
            cnn.Open();

            // wrap the connection with a profiling connection that tracks timings 
            return cnn;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> DapperTest()
        {
            using (OdbcConnection conn = GetConnection())
            {
                return conn.Query("SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects where is_ms_shipped = ?", new { is_ms_shipped = 1 });
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: From memory, ODBC / ifx has a lot of "issues" with named parameters. The query as shown *should* work in any sane, name-aware command. How close is the command shown to the *actual* code? does the code shown exhibit this problem?

Comment: I've just tried the code above to make sure it works in it's simplest form - and still no luck :(

Comment: can you include sample raw code that works directly against odbc connection

Comment: To add to Marc's comment, in my experience querying an Informix DB using ODBC can be frustrating. To find out the exact format in which ODBC is actually sending your queries to the database for evaluation, I've had quite a bit of success in the past using a packet sniffer like Wireshark and inspecting the raw data in the TCP/IP packets.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post, just use SP instead of query, please check this link [Dapper using ODBC store procedure Input parm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717971/dapper-using-odbc-store-procedure-input-parm-always-promt-xxx-was-not-supplied), this using sybase odbc Sp, all odbc use same technique, I wish it works in Informix.