# Adding parameters to a query with Informix and Dapper fails with syntax exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, informix, dapper

I'm attempting to use parameterized queries with Informix over ODBC, but any attempt to add parameters fails with this exception:

`$exception {"ERROR [42000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]A syntax error has occurred."}    System.Exception {IBM.Data.Informix.IfxException}`

Here is the code that fails:

`List<ItemAttribute> items = con.Query<ItemAttribute>("select * from oe_cnvwrk where cwr_genero = @cwr_genero", new{cwr_genero = cwr_genero}).ToList();`

Using it without parameters, like this example, works flawlessly, but opens the application up to injection attacks:

`ItemHeader itemHeader = con.Query<ItemHeader>("select * from oe_cnvhdr where hdr_control_id = " + hdr_control_id).Single();`

I was able to find a previously-listed question about this exact same issue here, but it was never answered. I'm hoping somebody will have an idea of how to handle the problem: [Dapper not adding parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509791/dapper-not-adding-parameters)

Any ideas a way to resolve this, or is there a different method for handling parameterization with Dapper that might work?

Comment: Uhm, are you sure that ODBC supports the @parametername syntax?

Comment: From memory, Informix only supports sequential `?` parameters, not named parameters. Dapper doesn't have good support for that at the moment, although it is something I would like to improve. Actually, I have most of the code I would need to *do this*, as I have been working on a java port of dapper, and jdbc does not have the concept of named parameters. I would be willing to look into merging those changes into dapper via a "use positional parameters" flag or similar. Thoughts?

Comment: That would be great of course. Would this open the path to OleDb providers? (Like... ahem... Access?)

Comment: @Steve presumably, yes

Comment: That would be very useful, yes, Mark!

Comment: @Steve fancy trying it? (see answer)

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry but I am in a very tight time constraints now. Perhaps next week.

Answer (score 6):

Not yet released to NuGet, but the [source code](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) now contains support for pseudo-positional parameters. These are implemented by pattern recognition, such that `?abc?` in your text maps to the parameter named from member `abc`, but using positional `?` syntax. So if you issue:

```
List<ItemAttribute> items = con.Query<ItemAttribute>(
    "select * from oe_cnvwrk where cwr_genero = ?cwr_genero?",
    new{cwr_genero = cwr_genero}).ToList();
```

it should work; the *actual* query executed is:

```
select * from oe_cnvwrk where cwr_genero = ?
```

where the parameter added is the one from the member marked `cwr_genero`. This allows the member to be resolved correctly. The special `?foo?` pattern is used as the indicator to switch to positional parameters.

Note that individual parameters can only be referenced *once* per query; the following will *not* work:

```
select * from sometable where foo = ?x? or bar = ?x?
```

Comment: Means we cannot use the same parameter (?a?) multiple times. I am using oracle

Comment: I have used :a instead of ?a? is it will be fine na?

Comment: @user960567 `:a` is not the positional option - that's named - so yes, named parameters should work fine. let me know if not

Comment: even :a shows same error I have created 2 variables for now